# de Rham cohomology groups with compact support

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

I am trying to solve the following questions regarding the de Rham cohomology groups with compact support: 1) $H^*_c(X):=\{H_c^k(X)\}^\infty_k$ where $k\geq 0$ is a graded algebra of $H^*(X)$    $\quad$ 2) if $X$ is a compact smooth manifold then $\Omega_c(X)=\Omega(X)$ and therefore $H^*_c(X)=H^*(X)$. **Note**: $\Omega_c(X)$ is the set of all smooth $k$-forms on a manifold $X$ with a compact support.

Comment: Which is the question? (1) is clear, yes, the canonical map from $H_c^*(X)\to H^*(X)$, induced on representatives by $\Omega_c(X)\to\Omega(X)$, is a map of graded algebras. (2) is clear, since on a **compact** manifold, $\Omega_c(X)=\Omega(X)$, any form has compact support, a closed set inside the compact $X$ being compact.

Comment: @dan_fulea What do you mean by "induced on representatives by"?

Comment: Every element from cohomology group can be realized as "one specific cycle modulo the module of boundaries". The one specific cycle is not determined, any choice is a "representative" for the class. But independently, which is the question?! Where is the proposition with a question mark in the OP? Please show than the own effort to solve the issues.

Comment: Hi @dan_fulea, both of the arguments (1 and 2) above are my questions. I wrote them as they are written in my notebook. I have tried to solve them, but unfourtantly I haven't succedeed. That's why  I asked them, hopping that I will get a hint so I can solve them.

Comment: So for (1): We know how to multiply differential forms on the manifold $X$. If $d\omega=d\eta=0$, then $d(\omega\eta)=(d\omega)\eta\pm \omega(d\eta)=0$. This gives the product structure on $H(X)=H^*(X)$. Restricting to forms with compact support we get the *sub*algebra structure on $H_c(X)$. In (2), $\Omega_c(X)=\Omega(X)$ is clear. We build the cohomology thus on the same complex, get the same cohomology, $H(X)=H_c(X)$. The claimed structures explain themselves from the definitions.